# display two tables into one using select sql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have Table A

```
============
| id | val |
=====+======
| 1  | abc |
| 1  | def |
| 2  | ghi |
| 2  | jkl |
============
```

I have Table B

```
============
| id | val2 |
=====+======
| 1  | rty |
| 1  | vbn |
| 2  | uio |
| 2  | zxc |
============
```

I want to display the two tables like this..

```
===================
| id | val | val2 |
=====+=====+=======
| 1  | abc | rty  |
| 1  | def | vbn  |
| 2  | ghi | uio  |
| 2  | jkl | zxc  |
===================
```

my problem is i am having redundancy..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like Gordon's approach, since it doesn't assume the same number of rows in each table, but here's a `JOIN` version:

```
SELECT a.id,a.val,b.val2
FROM (SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number
            ,id,val
      FROM Table1 a cross join (select @row_number := 0) b
      )a 
JOIN (SELECT @row_number2:=@row_number2+1 AS row_number2
            ,id,val2
      FROM Table2 a cross join (select @row_number2 := 0) b
      )b
 ON a.Row_Number = b.Row_Number2
  AND a.id = b.id
```

Here's a working version of his `UNION` version:

```
SELECT Row_Number,ID,MAX(Val) AS Val,MAX(Val2) AS Val2
FROM (SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number
            ,id,val,NULL as Val2
      FROM Table1 a cross join (select @row_number := 0) b      
      UNION ALL
      SELECT @row_number2:=@row_number2+1 AS row_number
            ,id,NULL,val2
      FROM Table2 a cross join (select @row_number2 := 0) b
      )sub
GROUP BY Row_Number,ID
```

Demo of both: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/223aa/9/0)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have a problem because you don't have a proper `join` key.  You can do this by using variables to create one.  Something like this will work for the data you provide:

```
select min(id), max(aval), max(bval)
from ((select id, val as aval, NULL as bval, @rna := @rna + 1 as seqnum
       from tablea a cross join (select @rna := 0)
      ) union all
      (select id, NULL val, @rnb := @rnb + 1 as seqnum
       from tableb b cross join (select @rnb := 0)
      )
     ) ab
group by seqnum;
```

Comment: im having a error [Err] 1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias.

Comment: can you explain the query in details..? in Table A i got the field priority_code, branch_code and in Table B i got priority_code, user_id

Comment: just add an alias after `cross join (select @rna := 0) b`

Comment: `[SQL] select min(a), max(aval), max(bval)
from ((select priority_code, branch_code as aval, NULL as bval, @rna := @rna + 1 as seqnum
       from sfa_priority_branch_account cross join (select @rna := 0) a
      ) union all
      (select priority_code, NULL user_id, @rnb := @rnb + 1 as seqnum, 'b' as which
       from sfa_priority_user_login_details b cross join (select @rnb := 0) b
      )
     ) ab
group by seqnum;
[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'a' in 'field list'` I GOT THIS ERROR @Hart CO

Comment: @user3109628 . . . That should have been `id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this using `INNER JOIN`. See my query below:

```
SELECT A.id,val,val2 FROM
(SELECT
     @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS RowNumber,
     id,
     val
FROM TableA, (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t ORDER BY val) AS A
INNER JOIN
(SELECT
     @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS RowNumber,
     id,
     val2
FROM TableB, (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t ORDER BY val2) AS B
ON A.RowNumber=B.RowNumber
```

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` is a good solution when available, but it's not a function in `MySQL`